# [ClientMissingIntents]: Valid intents must be provided for the Client Error When Running 'Node .' in VS Code Terminal

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Whenever I run `node .` in my project terminal I get *"[ClientMissingIntents]: Valid intents must be provided for the Client"* error. Before people ask if I'm using the correct version I'm on v14.11.0 and 20.3.1 node.js

My Code:

```js
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({
  intents: [
    GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages
  ]
});

const TOKEN = "[MY TOKEN]";
const PREFIX = "."
var bot = new Client();

bot.on("ready", function() {
    console.log("Ready");
});
bot.on("message", function (message) {
    if (message.author.equals(bot.user)) return;

    if (!message.content.startsWith(PREFIX)) return;

    var args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");

    switch (args[0]) {
        case "ping":
            message.channel.sendMessage("Pong!");
            break;
    }

});
```

I've uninstalled discord.js and re-installed it, made sure that intents were enabled on my bot through the discord developer portal, and looked on Google and have had no results.

Comment: Can I have full logs details which is posted to discord.

Comment: Can you post the whole file? it's working fine, but maybe there is something else. and provide your node version :)